# Is there any way to validate the width and height of image when uploaded?

Tags: validation

Is there any way to validate the width and height of image when uploaded?
using javascript of server side ? like jsp, aspx etc?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Java platform, you can use [ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to read the image, then use `getHeight` and `getWidth` on the [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) returned from the read operation.

I admit this is quite a heavyweight approach, so I'm sure there is an even better approach. I just have to find it. :-P

As for .NET, I have no idea. :-)

Comment: .NET is not very different from reading file properties on the Desktop. You just get the dimension of the image from file properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by execing the Image Magick "identify" command.

Easy enough if you're using Unix - although I think it runs on Windows too.

I doubt you can do it client-side.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the question is about how you would do it in a server-side environment (using JavaScript, rather than something like PHP, for the server logic), so it's not client-side at all. :-)

Comment: Ah yes, good point, I mis-read "using javascript of server side" to be "using javascript OR server side". :-)